# How to Schedule a windows service using topshelf in c# at specific time in a each day

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, topshelf

```
_timer = new Timer(1.8e+6) { AutoReset = true };
_timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
```

Comment: What did you find when you researched this task?

Comment: it was executing once for every half an hour. but i need it to execute once every day so pls help on this

Comment: So many low-quality questions! Please read related guides before submitting your question.

Comment: I need to execute using topshelf library not the old tradational approach of windows services if you could help

Comment: FYI: 1.8e+6 is 1800000 milliseconds, or 1800 seconds. 1800 seconds is 30 minutes.

Comment: If you are open to add an additional package to your project Quartz.NET is a scheduler library commonly used to build this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

To make it run for a specific time of a day you have to make your timer set for that Time/value by finding out the difference from the current time when your service starts, find the difference between your current time and your specific time and sets the timer with that value.

```
public void Start() 
{
  ResetTimer();
}

public void TimerElapsed (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever it is that you need to do on a timer
    ResetTimer();
}
public void ResetTimer()
{
        DateTime startTime=DateTime.Now;// = "current time";
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("Specific time to run the service");

        if (endTime < startTime)
        {
            endTime.AddDays(1);
        }           
        
        TimeSpan duration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);        
    
        _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration.Seconds), 
         TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration.Seconds));
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed; //if not set

}
```